# Making a serial connection via pySerial in Python

Tags: python, pyserial

I am trying to make a serial connection to a thermocouple thermometer, the PerfectPrime TC0309 via python to perform data logging within a program that monitors several other pieces of test equipment.

The manufacturer provides their own software to access the tool, and I've installed this and it works fine. The manufacturer also provide details on the serial connection, and I've successfully made a connection to the device using the Termite terminal running on a PC. I believe these results confirm the equipment and the cables are connected fine.

When I try to make a connection to the port using pySerial in python, I appear to successfully make a connection, but the same commands I use to poll the device in termite do not result in any serial data being available to read at the port.

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial()
ser.baudrate = 9600
ser.port = 'COM4'
ser.bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS
ser.stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE
ser.xonxoff = False
serial.dsrdtr = False
ser.rtscts = True  # In termite, works as True or Falso
ser.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE # In termite, works none and odd
ser.timeout = 0
ser.open()
ser.write(b'K') # 'K' sent as text in termite results in the model number being returned "0309"
buffer = ser.in_waiting
print(buffer)
ser.close()
```

I'm expecting data to be available in waiting, but the program always returns 0.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the device on the other end are not in echo mode. If so, the device won't send back what it received. It just receives silently.

About why it worked on other tools before, maybe it's because the tool offered local echo mode which looks like the device replied. For example, minicom supports enabling/disabling echo mode

> E    Toggle local echo on and off (if your version of minicom supports it).

From https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/minicom.1.html

Maybe it will be better to send some command that definitely triggers the device to reply something new.

A bit off the topic, I used the function readline instead and got the reply.

```
# Send text to UART
for byte_to_encode in text:
    uart.write(byte_to_encode.encode('utf-8'))
    time.sleep(0.05)

# Read and print all lines from UART until timeout
while True:
    line = uart.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    try:
        print(line.decode('utf-8').strip())
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        print(line.hex())
```

Or maybe you can try this https://github.com/sony/pyAutoPort instead if the messages are all in ascii. This is a tool made by me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try ser.write(b'K\n') or ser.write(b'K\r').
Some UART protocols read line by line, and the end of each line is marked by \n or \r. I have never used Termite terminal, but I have used the vsCode serial monitor extension, which automatically appends the \n or \r depending on the settings.

Comment: In termite, you can append either nothing, CR, LF, or CR-LF to each command. My device only works with 'nothing' appended.
In python, I tried with all four variations on the line ending, and none of them solicited a response. When I attempted it, I did it like you suggested for two of those variations.

Comment: Maybe set ser.timeout to 5 instead of zero. Check out: https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html. Also add ser.read() after ser.write(), since ser.read() is gonna block/wait for 5 seconds, since the thermometer needs a bit of time to respond.

Comment: Modifying the timeout a nonzero value up to 5 does not change the outcome. Adding ser.read() does not change it either.

Comment: I am out of ideas. Sorry. This is really a last resort measure and may not work: if you are currently using windows, maybe switch to a Linux device (e.g. Raspberry Pi). The reason I am suggesting this, is because my work laptop has extra anti-virus protection and different OS configuration, so it does not like Pyserial, when I never had this issue with pyserial on my personal windows computer. Linux environment is simpler without anti-virus or a complex OS, so Pyserial is less likely to clash with other programs.